# get KEY & VALUE from array in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array look like bleow

```
Array ( 
    [number] => 
         Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
               [0] => stdClass Object ( [phone_number] => 123456891 ) ) 
               [1] => Array ( 
                   [0] => stdClass Object ( [phone_number] => 2356894156 )      ) ) )
```

how can i retreive thos phone_numbers using for loop
Thank in advance

Comment: What you have tried so far post your attempts

Comment: can you please provide the exact loop.

Comment: Please provide your attempts else SO in not the correct place for _PLEASE CODE FOR ME_

Comment: foreach ($data as $array => $values) 
    {
     foreach($values as $v)
     {
      echo $v->phone_number."<br>";
     }
       
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
        $arr = [ 
                'number' => array ( 
                    '0' => array(
                        '0' => (object) array('phone_number'=>123456891)
                    ),

                    '1' => array(
                        '0' => (object) array('phone_number'=>2356894156)
                    )
                ) 
        ];

       foreach($arr as $val){
         foreach($val as $val1){
           foreach($val1 as $val2){
              echo $val2->phone_number."<br>";
           }
         }  
      }

?>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! You could improve this answer by also explaining what the code does. Code only answers might be tricky to understand for the OP as well as future visitors.